# How to know mqtt topics without client.subscribe() in python

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto

If a message is sent to the topic in an mqtt broker, I want to know the topic by Python. In order to use client.subscribe (), I have to manually enter a topic, so I need to know the topic before client.subscribe() dynamically. Is there a way to know what broker topics are?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Request all published topics](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42559890/request-all-published-topics)

Comment: Also just knowing the topics doesn't help if you don't also know the format of the data being published. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you send "EVERY" message to broker with retain message = True, then you can:

1. Connects to server with subscribe '#'
2. Check all the retain message and their topic (then you can got all topics)
3. Unsubscribe '#'
4. Subscribe the topic you want

This solution subscribe twice, may not fit your original requirement (only subscribe once), but can do what you want

Comment: You're welcome. If you like my answer, you can accept my answer by clicking the checkmark on the left side. Thanks! :)